# Update Parent ViewModel from Partial View Modal Popup Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net-core, keypress, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-partialview, ajaxform

I'm trying to read from a barcode scanner for two different objects. I read the inputs using jQuery events on `keypress` in order to grab the input. On my parent page, I have a button for each type of input that opens up a modal popup for the object type so that I can differentiate the source. In my modal popup, I am trying to make an AJAX call an action on the controller to read the input and populate the object in the parent view model. I am not sure the best way to go about this.

**Scanned Objects Model**

```cs
public class KeyCardCheckOutViewModel
{
  public Employee employee { get; set; }
  public KeyCard keyCard { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee**

```cs
public class Employee
{
  public string employeeId { get; set; }//more objects to be populated by AD through controller
}
```

**KeyCard**

```cs
public class KeyCard
{
  public string cardId { get; set; }
}
```

**KeyCardCheckOut View**

```
@model KeyCardCheckOut

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userIdModal">
    Scan ID
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#keyCardModal">
    Scan Key Card
</button>
<form method="post" asp-controller="Scanner" asp-action="Submit" id="testForm">
    <label>@Model.employee.employeeId</label>
    <label>@Model.keyCard.cardId</label>
    <partial name="/Views/Scanner/_UserIdPartial.cshtml" for=employee />
    <partial name="/Views/Scanner/_KeyCardPartial.cshtml" />
</form>
@Html.Hidden("OnScannedQRCodeUser", @Url.Action("OnScannedQRCodeUser", "Scanner"))
@Html.Hidden("OnScannedQRCodeKeyCard", @Url.Action("OnScannedQRCodeKeyCard", "Scanner"))
<script src="~/js/Scanner.js"></script>
```

**_UserIdPartial**

```
@model Employee
<form method="post" asp-controller="Scanner" asp-action="Submit" id="testForm">
<div class="modal" id="userIdModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="userIdModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="userIdModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody">
                Scan the Id Card
                <label>@Model.employeeId</label>
                <input asp-for="employeeId" type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Scanner">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Scanner.js**

```js
var _inputString = '';

(function ($) {
    _timeoutHandler = 0,
    _onKeypress = function (e) {
        if (this._timeoutHandler) {
            clearTimeout(this._timeoutHandler);
        }

        if (e.key != 'Enter') {
            _inputString = _inputString.concat(e.key);
        }

        this._timeoutHandler = setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
            if (_inputString.length <= 3) {
                _inputString = '';
                return;
            }
            $(e.target).trigger('altdeviceinput', _inputString);
            _inputString = '';

        }, this), 20);
    };
    $('#userIdModal').keypress(_onKeypress);
    $('#keyCardModal').keypress(_onKeypress);
})($);

$('#userIdModal').on('altdeviceinput', function () {
    var url = $('#OnScannedQRCodeUser').val();
    scannedQRCode(url)
});

$('#keyCardModal').on('altdeviceinput', function () {
    var url = $('#OnScannedQRCodeKeyCard').val();
    scannedQRCode(url);
});

scannedQRCode = function (url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: $('#testForm').serialize(),
        //data: { encryptedJson: _inputString},
        success: function (Response) {
            $("#testForm").html(Response);
            $("#userIdModal").modal('show');
        },
        error: function (Response) {
            alert("Failed");
        }
    });
}
```

**ScannerController**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult OnScannedQRCodeUser(Employee employee)
{
  employee.employeeId = "77";
//grab employee object info
  return PartialView("_UserIdPartial", employee);
}
```

This would let me scan an employee and post the information back to the parent page. I could then select one of the objects, rescan if I scanned the wrong object, or switch back and forth between the two. I might be going about this wrong, but I'm trying to avoid using a `ViewBag` and passing it through the URL since I'm staying on the same page.

Comment: Did you make any error by using such code?Also what is your `submit` method which is declared in your `_UserIdPartial`?

Comment: no errors just the html doesn't update correctly. The submit method isn't being used since I will probably be closing the modal via javascript.